# UEFI bootable Pendrive of Kali Linux

Tags: bootable-media, kali-linux

I have recently downloaded Kali linux 64 bit ISO Version 1.1.0a from [this](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) link. I am using Rufus to make a bootable pendrive for UEFI system type(using gpt partition scheme). Unfortunately an error has  occurred here is its image:

[image]

Here is another link which says that [Kali Linux 1.0.8 Released with EFI Boot Support](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-1-0-8-released-uefi-boot-support/).
So I also downloaded that ISO and tried to make a bootable pendrive using the above mentioned configuration. But the same error occured.

I am stuck at this point . Can anyone please help in solving this error.

Comment: A quick web search should have pointed you to [this](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux).

Comment: @Karan I have read that thread. That is a very old thread. Meanwhile Version 1.0.8 has been released with UEFI support. But it is also not working.

Comment: So you did not try the solution from that thread? When what you've done has failed what's the harm in trying this instead? Edit: If you're convinced that 1.0.8 has EFI boot support have you tried using the [recommended USB creation utility](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) instead of Rufus?

Comment: Bootable drive is working using  **Win32 Disk Imager** . How is it possible with it but not with **Rufus**?

Comment: For the record, this issue is entirely due to the incompetence of the [Kali Linux](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/526) and [Debian](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/531) developers who can't even implement UEFI support properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **Rufus** use [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to create bootable pen-drive.